# How to check if *either* character is in a string in Python?

Tags: python, string

I know about:

```
if 'a' in 'cat':
    win()
```

but is there a better way to finding if **either** of two letters exist in a string?

The following are some ways,

```
if 'a' in 'cat' or 'd' in 'cat':
    win()

if re.search( '.*[ad].*', 'cat' ):
    win()
```

**but is there something cleaner/faster/clearer?**

Like,

```
# not actual python code
if either ['a', 'd'] in 'cat':
    win()
```

Comment: `re.search(r'[ad]', 'cat')`? There is *no need* for the `.*` patterns in this case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i think the questions regarding  (cleaner , much efficient way to do this problem) are belongs to codereview.

Comment: `'a' in 'cat' or 'd' in 'cat'` is very clean, fast, and clear.  Why would you want to change it?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I voted to close this as too broad; the question is too thin to be a Code Review post however, as that requires *real working code*, not hypothetical questions.

Comment: @iCodez: not that it matters with *just three characters* but that does do two scans in the worst case scenario.

Comment: Given that you can omit .* in both occurrences of your second solution example (since you are using search not match), I see none of the other answers beating that in respect to clarity.

Comment: You can't pick faster and cleaner solution in a same time, you always have to state priorities. For faster solutions you may even use C: `import ctypes ; libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6") ; libc.strpbrk('cat', 'ad') != 0`, but it is definitely not a clean solution. So pick cleaner solutions where possible (`any`, `A or B`), and optimize them where needed depending on nature of data.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
if any(item in 'cat' for item in ['a', 'd']):  # Will evaluate to True
    win()
```

There is also the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) function which will check if **all** conditions are true:

```
if all(item in 'cat' for item in ['a', 'd']):  # Will evaluate to False
    win()
```

Comment: I hadn't known `any()` for way too long - what a miss.

Answer (score 7):

You could use sets:

```
if set('ab').intersection(set('cat')):
    win()
```

Comment: I think `set('cat')` is just fine

Comment: @myaut, nice, did not know that :) will edit to reflect. (I was using `set(list('cat'))`)

Comment: Actually `set('ab').intersection('cat')` is enough

Comment: @kolmar, great point, I will edit to reflect. (I was using `set(['a', 'b'])`)

Answer (score 0):

similar to selcuk's answer, except just using the truthiness of a list with items.

```
if [letter for letter in ['a','d'] if letter in 'cat']:
    win()
```

Comment: This is very difficult to read